# Perl regex: Extract token_key value from string

Tags: regex, perl, split

I just started learning Perl and trying to do regex to break down a token key.

The token itself has multiple "columns" and I only need the KEY section.

```
token:
{
    "token_key":"C9B3A703ADFEE7A579561799DC019685C75F16E6D4F80E3AA01798CA2B1BD4C396E91C62D73A9604EE90C72BED760AC24D70B072517B06C3D2E1E3102046103E813E2AA59741D2B6543475DEED4EF4A9625BFFF15DAC5417209AEED968016E0671BE1878C8",
    "key_type":"xyz",
    "expires":1200
}
```

but I only need this part

```
C9B3A703ADFEE7A579561799DC019685C75F16E6D4F80E3AA01798CA2B1BD4C396E91C62D73A9604EE90C72BED760AC24D70B072517B06C3D2E1E3102046103E813E2AA59741D2B6543475DEED4EF4A9625BFFF15DAC5417209AEED968016E0671BE1878C8
```

everything else can be ignored when I output it.

Any suggestions or advice are welcome!

Thank You!

Comment: If you're trying to manipulate JSON, then use the `JSON` module rather than trying to extract information from it yourself manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) -- perhaps a proper parser would be better?

```
use JSON::PP;
my $json = JSON::PP->new->utf8->allow_barekey;
my $token = $json->decode('{' . $str . '}')->{'token'};
print $token->{'token_key'};
```

In any case, you can extract it (a bit more hackishly) with a regex like so:

```
$str =~ /['"]token_key['"]:\s*['"]([a-f0-9]+)['"]/i;
print $1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  the regex worked perfectly! I was wondering if you could break it down for me on how each "pieces" work?  I think I have an idea, but I want to make sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: @user: Sure. `[]` means a character class, so `['"]` matches either a single or double quote. The `\s*` matches zero or more (`*`) whitespace (`\s`) characters. The `([a-f0-9]+)` matches a string of at least one (`+`) hex digits (`[a-f0-9]`) and puts it in a capturing group (`()`) for easy access later. The `i` modifier at the end indicates that the regex engine should ignore case when matching (so that `A123` is matched as well as `a123`).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less hackish regex would be:

```
 # (["'])\s*token_key\s*\1\s*:\s*(["'])((?:(?!\2)[\S\s])*)\2

 ( ["'] )                           # (1)
 \s* token_key \s* 
 \1 
 \s* : \s* 
 ( ["'] )                           # (2)
 (                                  # (3 start)
      (?:
           (?! \2 )
           [\S\s] 
      )*
 )                                  # (3 end)
 \2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

1. absence of white characters between "token_key" and its value,
2. double quotes, not single quotes have been used in parsed strings,
3. a string of file is in $_ variable.

In that case

```
    if (/"token_key":"([^"]+)/)
    { print "$1\n" }
```